# How to optimize Emoji rendering in android?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, caching, emoji

I am trying to make an emoji keyboard. I loaded some 1500 emojis in a `RecyclerView` using `EmojiTextView` as the item layout. However, I found that even simple scrolling was very slow by this simple approach.

I have initialized `EmojiCompat` library as below:

```
EmojiCompat.Config config = new BundledEmojiCompatConfig(this).setReplaceAll(true);
EmojiCompat emojiCompat = EmojiCompat.init(config);
```

The ViewHolder contains a single item i.e. `androidx.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView` and `holder.emojiTextView.setText(emojis.get(position).unicode);` sets the emoji in the holder.

I explored other emoji keyboards in github https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji. This repository uses a custom extended class from `AppCompatImageView` and Async-task to load drawable in background. It also optimizes loading by caching emoji's drawable using LRU cache.

However, these optimizations require a lot of boilerplate code.

So, my question is what all optimizations I can implement to load emojis smoothly while scrolling without building variants of imageView/textView from scratch and without handling the rendering of emojis myself.

How does android system handles the rendering and why it is not already optimized by default?

Can you also please point out some resources to learn more about caching/loading of emojis and ways to optimize using custom UI classes.

Comment: - Since the emoji compat library has to render each time on the bind view holder method, I think it will cost some time. I tried to use the process method, but that also doesn't improve the performance much. I think i need to generate image files for emojis i guess..

Comment: Hey @MonsterBrain, I think bundling all images of all emojis will surely increase the size of apk too much.

Comment: If you use webp format and use the emoji spritesheet (probably need some 2 or 3 sheets) you can get performance ... And in case of quality you might need to use the vector drawable or svgs ...